# Design of multi-threaded server in c

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, message-queue

When trying to implement a simple echo server with concurrent support on linux.

**Following approaches are used:**

- Use `pthread` functions to create a pool of thread, and maintained in a linked list. It's created on process start, and destroy on process termination.
- Main thread will accept request, and use a `POSIX message queue` to store accepted socket file descriptor.
- Threads in pool loop to read from message queue, and handle request it gets, when there is no request, it will block.

The program seems working now.

**The questions are:**

- Is it suitable to use `message queue` in the middle, is it efficient enough?
- What is the general approach to accomplish a thread tool that needs to handle concurrent request from multiple clients?
- If it's not proper to make threads in pool loop & block to retrieve msg from message queue, then how to deliver requests to threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems unneccesarily complicated to me. The usual approach for a multithreaded server is:

- Create a listen-socket in a thread process
- Accept the client-connections in a thread
- For each accepted client connection, create a new threads, which receives the corresponding file descriptor and does the work
- The worker thread closes the client connection, when it is fully handled

I do not see much benefit in prepopulating a thread-pool here.

**If you really want a threadpool:**

I would just use a linked list for accepted connections and a `pthread_mutex` to synchronize access to it:

- The listener-process enqueues client fds at the tail of the list.
- The clients dequeue it at the head.

If the queue is empty, the thread can wait on a variable (pthread_cond_wait) and are notified by the listener process (pthread_cond_signal) when connections are available.

**Another alternative**

Depending on the complexity of handling requests, it might be an option to make the server single-threaded, i.e. handle all connections in one thread. This eliminates context-switches altogether and can thus be very performant.

One drawback is, that only one CPU-core is used. To improve that, a hybrid-model can be used:

- Create one  worker-thread per core.
- Each thread handles simultaneously n connections.

You would however have to implement mechanisms to distribute the work fairly amongst the workers.

Comment: Before add the pool, an older version is the same as the described: create a new thread for each request, and terminate the thread after request fully handled. But, even though creating a thread is not that heavy, a heavy traffic might benefit from a thread pool, I guess, so I am trying to implement one.

Comment: @EricWang And why weren't you satisfied with that?

Comment: I updated  the comment. In heavy traffic server, would thread pool provide better performance than create/terminate thread for each request?

Comment: @EricWang I have put some more thoughts into the answer, maybe something inspires you

Comment: The `pthread_mutex` solution makes good sense to me, I would like to write an implementation with that.

Comment: @Ctx You don't have to implement a mechanism to distribute the work fairly amongst the workers, the OS already has one. Just have whatever thread is running do whatever work needs to be done.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This applied to the hybrid model, where inequal load can easily happen if you do not care about distribution.

Comment: @Ctx You don't want an equal load distribution, you want an optimal load distribution. The OS will give you this without you having to do anything special. You basically just have each thread do this: "If there's work to do, do it. If not, wait until there is." The OS scheduler already knows which thread is the best one to run, that's its job.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But it gives CPU-time regardless what exactly to do in this time. Does it handle a connection or accept a new connection? Dequeueing a new connection is done quickly, whereas handling it is not. So you should control which threads preferably should handle new connections and not leave that indeterminate to the scheduler. And yes, this is a real-life problem, which I have observed. It is, however, not too hard to avoid that. And equal _is_ optimal in many situations.

Comment: @Ctx That's exactly the reason you should leave it to the scheduler! Why bother trying to predict how long things will take in the hopes that you can distribute optimally when the scheduler *knows* which threads are busy, which cores are available, and so on?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You simply don't get it, sorry about that. Maybe my language is too bad. One last try: The scheduler would not only have to provide runtime to some code, but make sure, that the thread indeed accepts a new connection. This may or may not be the case, the probability of that depends on the complexity of the tasks to accomplish (i.e. the frequency in which the threads for themselves can accept new connections at all). It is a bit hard to explain, maybe you have to encounter this problem yourself to fully understand it.

Comment: @Ctx I have no idea what you're talking about. But if it's something rare and obscure, I am quite right to point out that it has no business being in a generic answer about basic threading models.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It is neither rare nor obscure. You were perfectly right when talking about the standard model (one thread per client connection), but you run quick into distribution problems when using the proposed hybrid model with a few threads handling several connections simultaneously.

Comment: @Ctx No, you don't. You just let the scheduler do it. There is no distribution problem at all in that case. Why would you think you can do a better job than the scheduler? Do you know something it doesn't?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Lets say we have two threads A and B. A is moderatly busy, B is very busy. Both threads get CPU-time and by chance, B comes more frequently to a point, where new connections are accepted (i.e. dequeued) while new connections are pending, than A (because A does other things in that time). You might think, that this will equalize over time, but depending on the nature of the work done this is often not the case. So the root cause is, that the scheduler distributes CPU-time fairly, but not the connections (One process may end with a single connection, while the other has many!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101335/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-ctx).

Comment: @Ctx I finished migration to use `pthread_mutex_t` & `pthread_condition_t`, and use linked list to maintain the accepted socket fd. Without `condition` it surely get into high cpu & dead lock, together with condition it works really well, very low cpu, thx.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using pthread_mutex, you will want to use pthread_cond_t (pthread condition), this will allow you to put the threads in the thread pool to sleep while they are not actually doing work. Otherwise, you will be wasting compute cycles if they are sitting there in a loop checking for something in the work queue.

I would definitely consider using C++ instead of just pure C. The reason I suggest it is that in C++ you are able to use templates. Using a pure virtual base class (lets call it: "vtask"), you can create templated derived classes that accept arguments and insert the arguments when the overloaded operator() is called, allowing for much, much more functionality in your tasks:

```
//============================================================================//

void* thread_pool::execute_thread()
{
    vtask* task = NULL;
    while(true)
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
        // Try to pick a task
        m_task_lock.lock();
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------//

        // We need to put condition.wait() in a loop for two reasons:
        // 1. There can be spurious wake-ups (due to signal/ENITR)
        // 2. When mutex is released for waiting, another thread can be waken up
        //    from a signal/broadcast and that thread can mess up the condition.
        //    So when the current thread wakes up the condition may no longer be
        //    actually true!
        while ((m_pool_state != state::STOPPED) && (m_main_tasks.empty()))
        {
            // Wait until there is a task in the queue
            // Unlock mutex while wait, then lock it back when signaled
            m_task_cond.wait(m_task_lock.base_mutex_ptr());
        }

        // If the thread was waked to notify process shutdown, return from here
        if (m_pool_state == state::STOPPED)
        {
            //m_has_exited.
            m_task_lock.unlock();
            //----------------------------------------------------------------//
            if(mad::details::allocator_list_tl::get_allocator_list_if_exists() &&
               tids.find(CORETHREADSELF()) != tids.end())
                mad::details::allocator_list_tl::get_allocator_list()
                        ->Destroy(tids.find(CORETHREADSELF())->second, 1);
            //----------------------------------------------------------------//

            CORETHREADEXIT(NULL);
        }

        task = m_main_tasks.front();
        m_main_tasks.pop_front();
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
        //run(task);
        // Unlock
        m_task_lock.unlock();
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------//

        // execute the task
        run(task);

        m_task_count -= 1;
        m_join_lock.lock();
        m_join_cond.signal();
        m_join_lock.unlock();

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
    }
    return NULL;
}

//============================================================================//

int thread_pool::add_task(vtask* task)
{
#ifndef ENABLE_THREADING
    run(task);
    return 0;
#endif

    if(!is_alive_flag)
    {
        run(task);
        return 0;
    }

    // do outside of lock because is thread-safe and needs to be updated as
    // soon as possible
    m_task_count += 1;

    m_task_lock.lock();

    // if the thread pool hasn't been initialize, initialize it
    if(m_pool_state == state::NONINIT)
        initialize_threadpool();

    // TODO: put a limit on how many tasks can be added at most
    m_main_tasks.push_back(task);

    // wake up one thread that is waiting for a task to be available
    m_task_cond.signal();

    m_task_lock.unlock();

    return 0;
}

//============================================================================//

void thread_pool::run(vtask*& task)
{
    (*task)();

    if(task->force_delete())
    {
        delete task;
        task = 0;
    } else {
        if(task->get() && !task->is_stored_elsewhere())
            save_task(task);
        else if(!task->is_stored_elsewhere())
        {
            delete task;
            task = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above, each created thread runs execute_thread() until the m_pool_state is set to state::STOPPED. You lock the m_task_lock, and if the state is not STOPPED and the list is empty, you pass the m_task_lock to your condition, which puts the thread to sleep and frees the lock. You create the tasks (not shown), add the task (m_task_count is an atomic, by the way, that is why it is thread safe). During the add task, the condition is signaled to wake up a thread, from which the thread proceeds from the m_task_cond.wait(m_task_lock.base_mutex_ptr()) section of execute_thread() after m_task_lock has been acquired and locked.

NOTE: this is a highly customized implementation that wraps most of the pthread functions/objects into C++ classes so copy-and-pasting will not work whatsoever... Sorry. And w.r.t. the thread_pool::run(), unless you are worrying about return values, the (*task)() line is all you need.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: the m_join_* references is for checking whether all the tasks have been completed. The main thread sits in a similar conditioned wait that checks whether all the tasks have been completed as this is necessary for the applications I use this implementation in before proceeding.

Comment: Yeah, combine with `pthread_cond_t`, it's useful to create a producer / consumer model, thx.

Comment: This is commonly referred to a work-stealing model and if you are using C++, your easiest implementation will probably be to just use TBB and I would highly recommend. This implementation performs just as well as TBB in a benchmark implementation comparing the compute times but the TBB implementation is much, much simpler. The only reason we pursed this implementation is because this implementation required virtually zero rewrite of the existing code, whereas implementing TBB would have required an almost complete rewrite (although not if we were able to use C++11 lambdas, which we couldn't).

Comment: I am very new to C++, but have planed to improve the skill, will refer to the code when I got the time.

Comment: I finished migration to use `pthread_mutex_t` & `pthread_condition_t`, and use linked list to maintain the accepted socket fd. Without `condition` it surely get into high cpu & dead lock, together with condition it works really well, very low cpu, thx.